# Sensitivity of measurement

Tags: calculus

From MIT's calculus class, [assignment 3](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/assignments/ps3.pdf) has an interesting question about calculating accuracy of a measurement (Part2 - Q3 (b)).

> Suppose that the Planet Quirk is a not only flat, but one-dimensional (a straight line). There are several satellites at height 20, 000 kilometres and you get readings saying that satellite 1 is directly above the point $x_1 ± 10^{-10}$ and is at a distance $h_1 = 21, 000 ± 10^{-2}$ from you, satellite 2 is directly above $x_2 ± 10^{-10}$, and at a distance $h_2 = 52,000 ± 10^{-2}$ . Where are you and to what accuracy? Hint: Consider separately the cases $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_2 > x_1$.

My attempt to the problem consisted of finding the ranges where I could be considering satellite 1 and 2 independently, then take the intersection of these ranges. The problem is that those ranges are in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$, so I don't how to calculate the **accuracy**.

For example considering satellite 1, if I am at a point $q$ where $q < x_1$, then $q \in [x_1 - 10^{-10} - L, x_1 + 10^{-10} - L]$, where $L = \sqrt{(h_1 + 10^{-2})^2 - 20000^2}$.

Comment: And the observer for which the question is asked is supposed to be on planet Quirk?

Comment: Yes, the observer is in planet Quirk.